# Rspec & FactoryGirl : prevent from generating emails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

Recently I had errors when running rspec tests around generating my mailer views, which made me realize that for some tests, 3 or 4 emails are generated because of the factories (eg. I create an Admin => a confirmation email is generated by devise).

Is there a way to prevent from generating some emails when the purpose of the test is not testing if an email is sent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of things you can do. Firstly, make sure that you have:

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :test
```

in config/environments/test.rb (I'm pretty sure this is set by default). This ensures that emails are not **sent**. However this will still generate them, then place them in an array (`ActionMailer::Base.deliveries`).

To stop them getting generated you could mock out your mailer method. Something like:

```
allow(MyMailer).to receive(:my_method).and_return { double("Mailer", :deliver => nil)}
```

Comment: you could alternatively mock your admin account

Comment: As you said  `config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :test` is set by default.
I was looking for something more global but I guess I'll have to stub my mailers.

Comment: The new rspec synthax is `allow(MyMailer).to receive(:my_method) { nil }` but I'm getting `undefined method `deliver' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: Fair enough - return a double that responds to deliver (edited)

Comment: I was going to say that! Thanks

Comment: Any idea why `allow_any_instance_of(MyMailer).to receive(:deliver).and_return(true)` doesn't seem to work? I have no errors but I still have my roadie errors showing when I use `allow_any_instance`

Comment: Because you're not allowing any instance, mailer methods are static method calls, so your calling it on the class, not an instance of the class.

Comment: yes, don't use `allow_any_instance`, just use `allow` (might need to add `and_return`)